# React, problem with passing state as props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I am quite new to React world, and I have this problem I am trying to solve, but I don't quite understand why it is happening.

So I want to pass the state of component to parent component and from parent component to child component and everything look okay, and in console log the state goes trough, but nothing changes. I believe there is a way I need to listen for state change or something within child component so it works. If I put true in the parent component, child component also get's true, but if I toggle it on click, it goes trough but nothing changes in the child component.

Also I understand my code is little rough right now ill reafactor it later, but right now I am trying to understand why it does not work.

If anyone could help me I would be thankful for it.

This is component that controls the state.. So the state passes from TurnOnBtn to App and from App it goes to TodoList

```
import "./Todo.css";

class TurnOnBtn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { display: false };
    this.handleState = this.handleState.bind(this);
  }

  handleState() {
    this.setState({ display: !this.state.display });
    this.props.checkDisplay(this.state.display);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleState} className="TurnOnBtn">
        <i className="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default TurnOnBtn;
```

parent component App

```
import TurnOnBtn from "./TurnOnBtn";
import TheMatrix from "./TheMatrxHasYou";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { display: true };
    this.checkDisplay = this.checkDisplay.bind(this);
  }

  checkDisplay(newDisplay) {
    this.setState({
      display: newDisplay,
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TodoList display={this.state.display} />
        <TheMatrix />
        <TurnOnBtn checkDisplay={this.checkDisplay} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

child component TodoList

```
import Todo from "./Todo";
import NewTodoForm from "./NewTodoForm";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import "./Todo.css";

class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      displayOn: this.props.display,
    };
    this.newTodo = this.newTodo.bind(this);
    this.editTodo = this.editTodo.bind(this);
    this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this);
  }

  editTodo(id, updatedTask) {
    const updatedTodo = this.state.todos.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        return { ...todo, todo: updatedTask };
      }
      return todo;
    });
    this.setState({
      todos: updatedTodo,
    });
    console.log(updatedTask);
  }

  deleteTodo(id) {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id),
    });
  }

  newTodo(newState) {
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, { ...newState }],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={this.state.displayOn ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }}
        className="Todo-screen"
      >
        {" "}
        <div className="TodoList">
          <div className="TodoList-todos">
            {" "}
            {this.state.todos.map((todo) => (
              <Todo
                key={uuid()}
                id={todo.id}
                active={todo.active}
                editTodo={this.editTodo}
                deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo}
                todoItem={todo.todo}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>{" "}
        <NewTodoForm newTodo={this.newTodo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug here is in these line of codes:

```js
handleState() {
  this.setState({ display: !this.state.display });
  this.props.checkDisplay(this.state.display);
}
```

Remember `setState` is an async function, so by the time you set a new state using `setState`, the value for `this.state` is not guaranteed changed.

One way to fix this is using the `setState` callback, which will run after the state is changed:

```js
handleState() {
  this.setState({ display: !this.state.display }, function() {
    this.props.checkDisplay(this.state.display);
  }); 
}
```

But you don't need to use another state to keep `display` state in `TurnOnBtn` as you can pass the toggle callback from the parent:

`App.js`

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { display: true };
    this.toggleDisplay = this.toggleDisplay.bind(this);
  }

  toggleDisplay() {
    this.setState({
      display: !this.state.display,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TodoList display={this.state.display} />
        <TheMatrix />
        <TurnOnBtn toggleDisplay={this.toggleDisplay} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`TurnOnBtn.js`

```js
class TurnOnBtn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleState = this.handleState.bind(this);
  }

  handleState() {
    this.props.toggleDisplay();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleState} className="TurnOnBtn">
        <i className="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```